# My clear phone case that I'm not using seems greasy or uncleaned?

Tags: cleaning, phone, grease

I have a clear phone case that is yellow throughout, which I've grown accustomed to, but one day I saw a clearer phone case and bought it, and left the old one aside.

A few days/weeks later I saw my old phone case and it wasn't clear? It was much more opaque and looked very cloudy, I thought maybe bacteria was growing on it so

I tried to clean it with alcohol which didn't work so then I put it in a small tub of hot water and soap which also didn't work.

Right now I don't know what to do with it, obviously, I should throw it out, but I want to know whats going on with my phone case before I do that. Another thing I want to add is that by touch it feels like a very greasy phone case, thinking that could be the case as stated before I washed it with hot water and soap which didn't work.

Comment: Hi smelsh929, Welcome to Lifehacks.Stackexchange. What exactly was your question? If you would like to know why this happens, it is not within the kinds of question we try to answer here. Look at the help topic link under the "hamburger" logo in the upper-right corner of the banner.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already tried to de-grease and to clean your phone case and it still seems greasy, yellowed, and dirty; possibly the plastic or silicone has deteriorated and it cannot be saved.

It happens.

Exposure to skin oils, and various things in our environment acts on the kind of plastic used for phone shock protection. It is relatively soft and porous material.

Tough resilient plastic cases don't absorb shocks so well as soft plastic although they are more scuff resistant.

It's a compromise between tough, chemical resistant plastic and softer, more fragile but resilient shock absorbing sponge-like stuff.

Comment: Plastics have *plasticizers* added, such as  phthalate esters, which seep to the surface and make it sticky. Cleaning with solvents may work for a while, but the plasticizers will rise again.